# debian installer doesnt allow for specific LUKS combination of multiple drives

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, debian, luks, debian-bookworm

so i have these 3 drives in my PC:

`/dev/sda` 240GB SSD `Sandisk SSDSDA240G`

`/dev/sdb` 1TB HDD `WDC WD10EZEX-08WN4A0`

`/dev/sdc` 2TB SSD `TS2TSSD230S`

i want to install Debian Bookworm (12) on `/dev/sda`. my plan is this:

`/dev/sda`: luks `/` partition + ESP

`/dev/sdb`: currently not relevant

`/dev/sdc`: luks `/home` partition

but, the debian installer doesn't allow doing that with either guided or manual partitioning.
can you help?

Answer (score 0):

**You combine two issues: encryption and multiple drives.**

Today I had to do a similar installation with the Debian 12 net installer and also ran into troubles, but happily  **was** able to set up multiple luks encrypted drives. **I used "LVM inside LUKS" scheme to merge the two drives together.** (On laptops I don't use ZSF, but on PC I prefer ZSF over lvm, btw.) Becasue your post started with good old "normal" partitioning (no LVM), and you were not even mentioning swap partition, I decided to aim for more inexperienced audience. So I explain more detailed what I did and add some side notes. It may feel overwhelming, but actually with some linux experience it is straight forward "dig deeper until fixed" approach.

**In case it all is too complicated or still not working: just unplug all except your one system (root) drive. And install your linux using "luks+lvm guided installation with separate (very small) home partition". Single drive installation is directly supported by the installer.** You can later add your other drives to the VG as new physical volume, extend your home to that space. And by learning while doing, you already have a working installation (with a small home at first)

## Install Base System

- Use advanced options -> expert installer
- **add installer components "crypto-dm-modules" and "parted-udeb"** to use luks when partition manually.  (besides some other components)
- work through the installer steps. The extra options mostly work with defaults, e.g. for network. For more details, especially (6.3.4. Partitioning and Mount Point Selection): [Chapter 6. Using the Debian Installer#Components](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/ch06s03.en.html)
- Manual partitioning: **Step "Create partitions"**

  - With name-labels I always use **separate name parts using underscore "_"** (not "-" nor " " as separator), I tend to have unique names for each and every single partition. It helps a lot when troubleshooting.
  - sata ssd drives are "sdX" and nvme ssd drives "nvmeX"
- /dev/sda - 240GB SSD Sandisk SSDSDA240G

  - Nr. 1:      600 KB | B  K  ESP |              efi_boot

    - use as: EFI-System-Partition" (sets ESP flag, and formats fat32)
    - boot flag set (the only partition that has boot flag)
  - Nr. 2:      2 GB |                         boot_clear

    - becomes unencrypted /boot
  - Nr. 3:      2 GB |                        boot_2

    - very optional, if you later want encrypted boot partition, but expect a lot of expert fiddling.
    - use as: "not use it" - that would come after initial installation
  - Nr. 4:    *max*  |                           debian_crypt_1

    - on creation just use size *max* to get the rest of drive. Or *90%* if you want some reserve space.
    - use as physical volume for encryption
- /dev/sdc - TS2TSSD230S

  - Nr. 1:   *max*    |                        debian_crypt_2

    - on creation just use size *max* to get the rest of drive. Or 90% if you want some reserve.
    - use as physical volume for encryption
- Manual partitioning: **Step Encrypted LUKS partitions**

  - confirm that you enter this phase
  - Create those LUKS partitions. You are offered  the *whole* long list of partitions and drives. Just select your two LUKS partitions (/dev/sda4 and /dev/sdc1) - they have "crypto" stated in the list.
  - on finishing (yes to "overwrite data?") they are filled with randomness. This **can take quite some time**. Don't abort.
  - You have multiple LUKS containers. But be aware: **Using the Debian Installer only have ONE SINGLE passphrase, equal for all LUKS partitions.** It makes much sense when it is about getting a set of drives just to boot up. When using e.g. Gentoo Linux one can have much more control for this details. But *just stick with this* during installation. (Debian also is a Linux using normal LUKS, so you can e.g. add more passphrases to the slots and tweak whatever weird detail you find neccessary... but not during this installer process, please)
- Manual partitioning: **Step "Logical Volume Manager - LVM"**

  - confirm that you enter this phase
  - create **one** volume group named "vg" (stick to this name, anything else could lead to surprises later, because this default name was long time "assumed" by other linux subthings and this even might be (probably is)  unneccessary nowadays, I still avoid surprises due to incomplete implementations)
  - add your two /dev/mapper/XXX_crypt devices as so called "physical volumes". **Here the magic happens and you merge the two drives into one single thing**, a logical volume group, one new drive "vg". (In case you want to initially install with only a single system drive, just add this one crypt device instead of two. And in the coming step create only a small lv_home logical volume, that will still fit into the vg)
  - create "Logical Volumes" (i.e. LVM-partitions inside encrypted LUKS container). I prefix "lv_" to the names, so later I can easily see which is lvm stuff and which is not. The initial size is not soo important. After installation, you can add more memory to the partitions ("Expand") as long as you did not use up the whole available space of the "vg"). I tend to keep some reserves unallocated, so later during the years I can increase where needed (for you: / or /home).

    - "lv_swap", make it large enough to save the *whole* RAM - beware GB(base10) is not GiB (base2), "32GB RAM" almost ever is ment as 32GiB. If unsure add some safety buffer. This swap is used to "hibernate to disk" later, and it would be sad if hibernate crashed just because swap is a bit too small)
    - "lv_root" - I could spent 50-70GiB on it - really depends on. Normally 30-40GiB would be OK, but once you use space intensive stuff like e.g. plenty docker images (inside /var) or huge databases, you need much more (>>250GiB). Can be extended later.
    - "lv_home" - as much as you initially want and some more for the next time to come, but remember: you can extend later.
    - finish this LVM step and return to the manual partition page.
- Manual partitioning: **Step "Setting Mountpoints and Options"**

  - this assembles all together, at the end-user (unencrypted) partition side. You see a long list of stuff, but only focus to the end-of-chain partitions and logical volumes (after LUKS and LVM have done their job)
  - since you are **using ssd drives, you better reduce unneeded write load. One major step is to activate filesystem mount-flags discard,noatime,nodiratime**. There are more tweaking steps, but all can be improved later after initial install. (So beyond this already too long wall of text).
  - *lv_home*

    - use as ext4 with flags "discard,noatime,nodiratime,usrquota,grpquota,user_xattr"
    - mount point: **/home**
    - name "home"
    - 1% reserved for root (the default of 5% is way too much for larger filesystems, that are not really needed by root)
    - typical usage: standard
  - *lv_root*

    - use as ext4 with flags "discard,noatime,nodiratime,usrquota,grpquota,user_xattr"
    - mount point: **/**
    - name "root"
    - 5% reserved for root (doesn't matter much here)
    - typical usage: standard
  - **lv_swap**

    - use as: swap (no more options here needed)
  - **sda1 "ESP efi_boot"** (was already set up earlier)

    - use as EFI-Boot, Boot flag: on
  - **sda2 "boot_clear"**

    - use as ext4 with flags "discard,noatime,nodiratime,usrquota,grpquota,user_xattr"
    - mount point: **/boot**
    - name "boot"
    - 5% reserved for root (doesn't matter much)
    - typical usage: standard

Now just continue installing. Once installing finished, on reboot you will be prompted for your ONE luks passphrase, which opens all LUKS containers you have created. But **here** your two luks containers need extra tweaking. That is done in the next step.

## Manually Add Support of Multiple LUKS Partitions

If you now unplug your installer media and **just reboot your system, it will fail.** You will have to add post-installation tweaks.

### Notes Only for the Curious Ones

After entering passphrase for your first encrypted partition, it states
"gave up waiting for root file system device." and you land inside the *init boot stage* (initramfs as your root filesystem) and get some extra hints what to do:

> common problems: boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
>
> - check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
> - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev )
>
> ALERT /dev/mapper/vg-lv_root does not exist. Dropping to a shell

Now you can inspect your init stage to find the problem. Of course you will type what was hinted to you, but to no avail:

```
cat /proc/cmdline
```

> BOOT_IMAGE=/mvlinuz-6.1.0-17-amd64 root=/dev/mapper/vg-lv_root ro
> quiet

```
cat /proc/modules
```

> [-> long list, happily including dm_crypt dm_mod cryptd]

```
lvm pvs
```

> ```
> WARNING could not find device UUIOD <nvme1n1p1>
> missing /dev/mapper/nvme1n1p1_crypt
> ```

```
cryptsetup open /dev/nvme1n1p1 nvme1n1p1_crypt
```

Now type in your passphrase and voila: That worked. It also triggers the lvm-system to make all your logical volumes inside that now opened LUKS container to become available.

```
ls /dev/mapper
```

> [shows vg-lv_root vg-lv_home ]

```
cat /cryptroot/crypttab
```

**Here is the actual problem: inside initramfs the file */cryptroot/crypttab* has only one line for one of the two LUKS container.** But it should have listed both.

Now you have to care for your crypttab files - one is in your installed system in */etc/crypttab*,  and one inside the initramfs of the booting process, hidden inside the */boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-17* file (your version numbers will differ, of course. And you accumulate more of them with every kernel update.)  [Crypttab Format](https://manpages.debian.org/bookworm/cryptsetup/crypttab.5.en.html) has further information.

Especially look at the **option initramfs**

> "The initramfs hook processes the root device, any resume devices and
> any devices with the initramfs option set. These devices are processed
> within the initramfs stage of boot. As an example, that allows the use
> of remote unlocking using dropbear.
>
> This option is specific to the Debian crypttab format. It's not
> supported by systemd."

**So we have to add option *initramfs* to each line inside the /etc/crypttab file of your system, and recreate and reinstall initramfs foreach kernel version.**

### Solution

Reboot into installer medium and **start a rescue session**. The debian installer already prepares most of the work for you. (Compare with the [Documentation for the Debian live-medium](https://wiki.debian.org/RescueLive).) Once inside your installed system you need to fix and update the initramfs.

Start rescue mode

- do your language/network etc. stuff.
- And you are asked for passphrases to open your two encrypted LUKS partitions. Do so.
- select */dev/vg-lv_root* as your root.
- mount your separate boot partition to /boot (Yes, you want that)
- mount your separate ESP/efi partition to /boot/efi. (Yes, again)
- you want to execute a shell in */dev/vg/lv_root*

Then you land on a root shell *inside* your installed debian system, and can
fix the initramfs.

But first you mount your missing lvm partitions, in your case it's only lv_home.
(lv_root was already mounted to / by executing a shell in lv_root.)

```
mount /dev/mapper/vg-lv_home /home
mount
```

**Reassure, that your boot_clear partition is actually mounted to /boot.** Otherwise mount it, too.

```
cat /etc/crypttab
```

There must be a line for each of your XXX_crypt partitions of your ssd drives. And you see a UUID for each.
**But the initramfs option is not there, so only the root device is opened during boot**.

So add "initramfs" option behind the other options "luks,discard", **of BOTH lines**.

```
nano /etc/crypttab
```

> [..]_crypt UUID=[..] none luks,discard,initramfs

The next steps **require the file */etc/crypttab* to contain a valid line for each and all your (two) XXX_crypt partitions.**

You may recheck if UUID point to the correct partition, by browsing your UUIDs: `lsblk -f | less`

For my test setup */etc/crypttab* was OK, but the one inside the initramfs (for me it was */boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-17*) missed the line for the second XXX_crypt partition.

create new initramfs files and install them to /boot:

```
update-initramfs -u -k all
```

**That was it!**

Just normally reboot into your installed system and hopefully all is
working as expected. On boot you should be prompted for your
passphrase for both luks containers.

You could inspect the newly created initrd.img
file(s), to see if the crypttab now has two proper lines for your two
luks containers instead of only one. [How to check Contents of Initramfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716652/how-do-i-view-contents-of-initramfs-img-in-debian-based-distributions)

```
mkdir /tmp/initram && cd /tmp/initram
cp  /boot/initrd.img-6.1.0-17 ./
unmkinitramfs initrd.img-6.1.0-17 ./initramfs
cat ./initramfs/main/cryptroot/crypttab
```

(That is content of the once faulty file, now hopefully fixed - you now have one line for each of your luks partitions, right?)

## Last Words

Remember: your ESP and your boot partition is not encrypted, and your UEFI/bios mostly is also open to a variety of attack vectors. So probably are your peripherial devices (USB slots e.g. open a nice way into your system) For that you should really re-consider your risk profile before digging deeper. But have fun when making aquaintance with OPSEC and installing e.g. QubesOS on a 2nd laptop ... or: leave it as it is.

With all this done, maybe you want to see inside your new debian system what pile of interconnected storage things you have created. Nowadays linux systems use unique ids (=UUID) for each [drive, partition, logical volume, raid etc etc]. To see them all try `lsblk -f`.

Further readings

- SOLVED update-initramfs within a chroot, Debian Buster 2019-08-18
  16:34 https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=143279
- Full disk encryption (including boot) on Debian Bookworm
  https://www.dwarmstrong.org/fde-debian/
- Full Disk Encryption in Debian 12 Bookworm, Including Boot with LVM
  https://linuxgeek11.github.io/2023/10/03/debian-12-bookworm-full-disk-encryption-boot.html